# Is there a PyMOD(DEINIT)_FUNC?

Tags: python, python-3.4, python-c-extension

I want to know whether there is a `PyMOD(DEINIT)_FUNC`?, I know that resources are released when the python script exits, but I would like to make my code as responsible for the memory it uses as possible.

I have searched the documentaion of course, and until now I think there is no function called from python core to the c module when the module is unloaded, but I hope there is and I just don't know how to search.

Comment: Please tag your python version. Also have a look at https://bugs.python.org/issue9072, especially "*Please accept that Python indeed does not support unloading modules for severe, fundamental, insurmountable, technical problems, in 2.x.*"

Comment: Also relevant is [PEP 3121](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3121/): *In addition to the initialization function, a module may implement a number of additional callback functions, which are invoked when the module's tp_traverse, tp_clear, and tp_free functions are invoked, and when the module is reloaded.* This is implemented for Python 3, not Python 2, so your exact version is important.

Comment: @dhke I often forget how irritating it is that there is so much difference between versions, and how many many projects stick to python2, I however have faith that someday everyone will migrate to python3 and I do everything with python3, specially c modules.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python 2 does not support module finalisation, no. See [bug 9072](https://bugs.python.org/issue9072):

> Please accept that Python indeed does not support unloading modules for severe, fundamental, insurmountable, technical problems, in 2.x.

For Python 3, the C API for module initialisation was overhauled (see [PEP 3121](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3121/)) and the new [`PyModuleDef` struct](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/module.html#c.PyModuleDef) has a [`m_free` slot](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/module.html#c.PyModuleDef.m_free) that takes a callback function; use that to clear out your module memory.